# react native - How to insert image to TextInput after uploading immediately

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a post editing interface works as follow:
user can input text, and when he/she presses the image upload button, after the image is uploaded to the server, the uploaded image need to be inserted after the current cursor, and user can continue to input the text.

How can I achieve this in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? It's always better to try and post your current code so that we can help you.

I see two parts to your question

1) Image uploading - You can use a library for picking the image (e.g - https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker). Then when you get the asset url from the image picker library you can use a file upload library (e.g - https://github.com/aroth/react-native-uploader) to upload this to your server and get the stored url back from the server as the response.

2) Image Displaying - For this you can use a native  and set its source using the url returned by your server.